# Django Celery set individual logfile path for each task

Tags: django, celery, fabric, logfile

I am trying to execute a fabric function defined in a fabfile as a celery task.
Now i need to create a separate log file everytime the task is executed. How can I
set the logfile path everytime depending on timestamp. I need to give the link of this
logfile in the end to be available for download so that the user can see the entire 
deployment process or error in the process.

Thanks,
Rohan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`task.get_logger` supports a `logfile` argument, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
@task
def mytask():
    logger = self.get_logger(logfile="foo.log")
    logger.info("logging from mytask")
```